# DotNetHighcharts- Can I assign my whole chart to a JS var after page load, for further manipulation

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

I'm using DotNetHighcharts to create a bar column chart but due to the lack of development work on DotNetHighcharts I need to make use of javascript to disable the print Button by itself (keeping the other export options in tact).

I've searched for a long time and haven't found an answer to this, but am wondering if there is a way to load my highchart in the normal fashion, and when the document is ready to manipulate the chart using the usual highcharts javascript functions.

Can this be done?

Comment: This can absolutely be done, with some constraints. Most easily, you can assign the chart options to a variable, including its generation to a container, and manipulate it later. If you look at this demo (http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-addpoint-append/), they assign the chart to a variable and then change the series data based on that variable's values. Is this what you're looking for? If so, I can give you more concrete examples.

Comment: yes like this, except I generate all my seriesData in my c# helper, and my chart is just loaded into a container Div.  Can I get the chart by referring to this container div? All I want to do is hide the Print Chart button independent of the other exporting options

Comment: I'm not a c# person, so please forgive my question, but, are you able to set Highcharts options prior to your helper? There is a Javascript function called `Highcharts.setOptions()` wherein you can state what kind of options you want applied to a chart at a global level, including export options. If this is something you can call prior to drawing the chart, then, yes, you can absolutely remove the print option. I can show you how.

Comment: you can, and there used to be the option for buttons: { printButton: { enabled: false } }   but not anymore for some reason. Now in the newest version printButton etc is replaced with one option, contextButton: { MenuItems : ... }   but i have no idea how to manipulate this to do what I need and the documentation is very poor

Comment: I dont like saying this but I would abandon the dotnethighcharts method. It is not updated to latest highcharts.js code so it has no knowledge of new parameters/options. You are going to either have to expand the dotnethighcharts c# library yourself to add these options or generate your own javascript that you can register on the page. We went with the latter option as it provides much more control.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon my comments to your question, you can define what shows up in the export menu by setting the `contextButton` attribute in either the global `Highcharts.setOptions()` function or in your local chart options. Doing so will overwrite the default export options that are brought in by the `exporting.js` module.

Here's an example below that will populate the export menu with options to export the chart as a PNG, JPEG, SVG, or PDF, but not show the print button.

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        contextButton: {
            text: 'Export',
            menuItems: [
                {
                    text: 'Save as PNG',
                    onclick: function () {
                        this.exportChart();
                    }
                }, {
                    text: 'Save as JPEG',
                    onclick: function () {
                        this.exportChart({ type: 'image/jpeg' });
                    }
                }, {
                    text: 'Save as SVG',
                    onclick: function () {
                        this.exportChart({ type: 'image/svg+xml' });
                    }
                }, {
                    text: 'Save as PDF',
                    onclick: function () {
                        this.exportChart({ type: 'application/pdf' });
                    },
                }
            ]
        }
    }
},
```

I have a fiddle that I created for another question here on Stack Overflow that shows these options in context: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/00wrak9v/. In this instance, I set local `contextButton` options to trigger Google Analytics events, but you could include any type of event you'd like when a user chooses a particular export option, or, for that matter, rearrange, add, or remove certain options.

I hope this is helpful for you!